# High Poly -> Low Poly Texture Bake Problem (UV seems to be ignored entirely)

Tags: uv, texture-baking, photogrammetry

I've been following this awesome tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dc4KN2bdrw&ab_channel=BlenderBones) on converting photo scanned objects to usable, low poly objects. I've been able to follow everything up to the part of baking the diffuse textures from the high poly object to the low poly object (Link to time stamp on video: https://youtu.be/-dc4KN2bdrw?t=361). It's not working like his. It's doing this and have no idea what it could be doing.

[image]

I remapped the UV's of my lower poly object to make more sense and note there is dramatic difference between the high and low poly model UV's, but every attempt at trying to maintain the high res textures onto this low res model has not been working correctly giving very strange outputs for textures and looks like it completely ignores the UV mapping of my low poly object.

I've toyed around a lot with the render settings but still don't get adequate results. I've attached a link to google drive with more pictures. Would appreciate any knowledge and help.

(MORE IMAGES) >> https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14LWVC06HjRELwkHG6kgQVPMJlMSkMsnj?usp=sharing

Comment: You don't have any pictures of your UV map.  That's the first thing I would look at.  The second thing I would look at would be if you have multiple UV maps.  A link to a file would let people look at that, as well as any other details, more easily.

Comment: @Nathan - Thanks for your response. I just uploaded the project file and some pictures of the UV maps of the high res tree and the low res tree to the google drive folder. Would you check that out?

Just as a note, one of the UV's was out of place because i was moving it around to test if I could bake the texture from the high res to a duplicate high res model. It worked! However when I tried scaling one of the islands in the UV it seemed to have a lot more trouble matching the texture to that UV.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14LWVC06HjRELwkHG6kgQVPMJlMSkMsnj?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, Nathan. You're right about the dirty UVs being show stopper. Nothing would've worked without cleaning my UVs up and it makes sense to me why it would be one big blob now. After cleaning I got these results:

[image]

So it still wasn't quite working but I continued to play with some of the render settings and I simply changed my "Max Ray Distance" to 0 and it came out just right!

[image]

I'm not even sure the science behind the ray distance, but changing it to 0 worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Your object does not have a good UV map:

[image]

We can see that there is at least one face that occupies the entire 0,1 UV space.  Other faces overlap with this face.

To get a reasonable bake, you cannot have any overlap in your UVs in the 0,1 space.

There may be other problems as well, but this is a show-stopper that needs to be fixed before any texture bake has any possibility of doing what you want.

We can also see, in the 3D viewport, that there are a lot of loose vertices that you should probably clean up.

BTW, why disable overlays in UV?  This will confuse people who inspect your file, and the only reason to use the UV editor is to edit UVs, which cannot be done when overlays are disabled.  If you want to just look at your image in 2D, use an image editor viewport.